# How to identify counterfeit Analog Device products?

Tags: analog, dds

Recently I bought two AD9850 DDSs from a friend ( I think he had bought them from his home country).They worked just for minutes!  After hours challenging with them, I thought problem is because of my PCB layout and re-designed it. Finally I found out that the device had been a fake one ( my friend said he had bought them with a price much less than the company price!).

Now I want to buy them again but I am afraid of the same scenario. Is there any sign that I can distinguish a fake product from its package?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider sticking to reputable sources instead.

Comment: Analog Devices Authorized Sellers and Distributors: http://www.analog.com/salesdir/continent.asp

Comment: You may want to follow Bunnie Huang's blog because he covers topics like this in great detail. http://www.bunniestudios.com/ and search for "fake".

Comment: Given that the part in question is a fairly sophisticated DDS IC, and you mention "*They worked just for minutes*", odds are that the problem lies not in the IC but in the circuit board: It would be non-trivial to manufacture working AD9850 ICs. On the other hand, AD9850 is one of the few ICs that are sold at a huge premium (10x or more) on sites like Digikey, compared to its street price in China - Not sure why.

Comment: Someone talked my buyer into this thing that is supposed to be an AD822. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojPrs.png) Stopped that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to always buy from an authorized seller or distributor. You're taking a risk with anyone else.

There are ways to detect whether the device is counterfeit, but this depends on how good of a fake did they counterfeiters made. In some cases the packaging will be different in color (a different shade of white) or will be missing details in the markings, but in general there is not a single way to tell.

If it looks too good to be true, it probably is.

Comment: On the other hand manufacturer may have undocumented variations in production. For example same device made at different plants could look differently. Sometimes, this is not mentioned in the datasheet. Only way to be sure is to contact manufacturer and hope that they provide some identification information.

Answer (score 1):

1- All AD current devices are laser marked (Engraved) and not printed. If your device's marking are printed then it is very suspect. There are plenty of articles regarding AD reject devices finding their way back on the market. China is the worst place to buy any device.

2- Since your device worked for a bit, then it is possible you are using the wrong supply voltage. Check the full coding of the device against the data sheets.